# adding multiple produt to shopping cart by entering multiple product ID in a textbox

Tags: javascript, magento, jquery, e-commerce

I am developing an option in Magento where the customer can enter multiple product ID's in a text box and add them to Shopping Cart.
I have been able to do it for only one product ID where it is entered in a input box by using the following jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            var id = $("#nam").val();
            $.post("....../checkout/cart/add", { product:id },
            function(data) {
                alert("The Product is added to your shopping cart.");
                window.location.reload(true);
            });
        });
    });
```

var id fetches the value of the input box.

In an input box I am taking one product ID and so it's no problem in fetching the value and passing it to the add product page by using jquery.post().
But if I enter several product ID's separated by comma in a text box how will I fetch each productID and send it to add product page for updating ?
Is there any better way to do it other than using jquery.post() method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your Ids by a separator and iterate over the resulting array adding the items to the shopping card. Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            var ids = $("#nam").val().split(' '); // SPACE seperated Ids
            for(i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
              var id = ids[i];
              $.post("....../checkout/cart/add", { product:id },
              function(data) {
                //alert("The Product is added to your shopping cart.");
                //window.location.reload(true);
              });
            }
        });
    });
```

You will have to sanitize your textbox values before doing so.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#submit").click(function () {
                    var productIds = [];

                    $.each($("#nam").val().split(','), function (i, value) {
                        if (value.length > 0) {
                            productIds.push(value);
                        }
                    });

                    $.post("....../checkout/cart/add", { productIds: productIds },
                                                          function (data) {
                                                              alert('The' + (productIds.length == 1 ? 'Product' : 'Products') + ' is added to your shopping cart.');
                                                              window.location.reload(true);
                                                          });
                });
            });

            public ActionResult add(int[] productIds)
            {
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

you need to return array of product ids to post action then only it can be achieved.